# No carga el google map habiendo creado una api en google api console

Tags: google-maps

He dado de alta una Api para insertar un mapa de google pero no me carga el mapa en la web.

En la consola me da el error:

> InvalidValueError: initialise is not a function.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAbAymW3TTBTkQ-vDS-8r3nvBxVnWlfqcY&sensor=false&region=ES&callback=initialise"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialise() {
  var coordenadas = new google.maps.LatLng(38.959777, -3.886762); 
  var colores = [{
    featureType: "all", 
    elementType: "all", 
    stylers: [
      {saturation: -100},
      {lightness:0}, 
      {invert_lightness:false}
    ]
  }]; 
  var opciones = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: coordenadas,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }; 
  var mapa = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mi-mapa'), opciones); 
  var estilo = new google.maps.StyledMapType(colores); mapa.mapTypes.set('mapa-bn', estilo); mapa.setMapTypeId('mapa-bn'); 
  var marcador = new google.maps.Marker({  
    position: coordenadas,
    map: mapa,
    title: 'Empresa',
    icon: 'images/logo.png'  
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialise);
</script>
```

el mapa aparece y luego desaparece en menos de un segundo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He borrado la credencial que me dio google y he generado otra api key con otro correo electrónico y se ha solucionado todo manteniendo los scripts iniciales en la págna web.
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Estás llamando dos veces a `initialise`

Una cuando se gatilla el evento Load de la ventana

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialise);
```

Y otra cuando se completa la carga de los scripts de google y se ejecuta el callback:

```
...&sensor=false&region=ES&callback=initialise
```

El error que te da es porque una de las dos intenta ejecutar initialise antes de que se haya decladado.

Yo te aconsejaría quitar el listener de window.onLoad, y mover el llamado al script de google.maps al final del documento.